# Setting class attributes to attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, object

So I am trying to set a class with attributes that also have attributes in Python 3. Something similar to this:

```
ClassNo1.attr1.attr2.attr3 = 'somedatahere'
```

How can I do this in Python. I know that in Matlab you can do this by simply creating a struct but not sure how Python might do this.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have the equivalent of matlab structs. To achieve the behavior you desire, you need to have attr1 be an instance of a class which has a property named attr2. attr2, similarly, must be an instance of a class which has a property named attr3.

You can find Python class definition syntax here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html